# How to run RSpec scripts with custom arguments

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a specific requirement to run the RSpec scripts by supplying the configuration file during the run time.

RSpec doesn't allow you to supply the custom arguments through command-line except the pre-defined ones like "--tag, --format, --output etc.."

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging in through various online resources and stackoverflow, I found a workaround for this:

By using `dotenv` gem, you can achieve this.

Install the dotenv

```
$ gem install dotenv
```

create .env file in the test script folder with your custom arguments as a "KEY=VALUE" pairs, e.x:

```
CONFIG_FILE=test_config.yaml
```

Read the values as environment variables in your Spec file

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load

describe "Passing Arguments" do
  before(:all) do
    @configFile = ENV['CONFIG_FILE']
  end

  it "Initiating Device config" do
    puts "Using device config file #{@configFile}"
  end
end
```

Now you read the config file name as an environment variable in your test scrips.